# Some problems with segue and splash screen

Tags: objective-c, sdk, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to make a splash screen, but tutorial says, I should make a segue from StatusBar of the ViewController, where my Splash screen is, to the next one ViewController, that is a start page. This tutorial is obviously too old, because I have the last XCode. 
How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `storyboard`, insert a `UINavigationController` and connect it to the `UIViewController` you want to make your splash screen. If you haven't created any, you can use the `UIVewController` that will be inserted with the `UINavigationController` you drag into your `storyboard`. Now create new `classes` of type `UIViewController` and set them as `Custom Class` for the splash screen in the `storyboard` (inside the `Identity inspector`). Into the .m file you have to insert following code to perform a `segue` to another `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self performSelector:@selector(goToLandingPage)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:3.0f];
}


- (void)goToLandingPage{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"landingpage" sender:self];
}
```

Next you have to create a second `UIViewController inside the`storyboard`and drag a segue from the splash to the next`UIViewController`(don't forget to press`STRG`, and zoom out). Click on this`segue`and insert the identifier (in the`Attributes Inspector` on the right), in my case **landingpage**.

Everytime you want to perform a segue programmatically inside your code, you have to select the `UIViewController` it self inside the `storyboard` and drag it to the `controller` you want. Otherwise just use a `UIButton` and it will perform by click.